# Multiple Scopes for ServiceWorker Register method

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I was currently using 1 scope. However as the application grew, I need to add 1 more scope to the register method. How to do it.

```
navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl, {scope: '\src\'})
```

Now I need to add 1 more scope `\resource`. I can not user `.\` as it would create huge resource set.

Comment: I think this one is just a proposal and no working example as of the moment. See this [Github post](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/566). Hope this gave you some idea.